# Changing the global “path” from within a function?

Tags: zsh

My `zshenv` file has a bunch of lines like

```
if [[ -d "$HOME/bin" ]]; then
    path=($HOME/bin $path)
fi
```

I thought I’d try to factor this pattern out into a function. I replaced it with

```
function prepend_to_path_if_exists() {
    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        path=($1 $path)
    fi
}
prepend_to_path_if_exists("$HOME/bin")
```

but this gives the error

> /Users/bdesham/.zshenv:8: missing end of string

where line 8 is the one where I’m calling `prepend_to_path_if_exists`. What exactly is causing this error, and how can I make this function work? I’m using zsh 5.0.5 on OS X 10.10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call functions as with usual command executions like this (without `()`):

```
prepend_to_path_if_exists "$HOME/bin"
```

It seems that zsh try to expand the glob `prepend_to_path_if_exists(…)` rather than to call the function.

---

TL;DR: Prepending emelemnts to `$path` would be accomplished by a little cryptic way:
(I'm not quite sure that the below form is preferable for anyone though.)

```shell
# `typeset -U` uniqify the elements of array.
# It could be good for $path.
typeset -U path

# prepending some paths unconditionally,
path[1,0]=(\
  $HOME/bin \
  $HOME/sbin \
)

# then filtering out unnecessary entries afterward.
path=(${^path}(-/N))
```

The `$path[x,0]=…` is prepending(splicing) element(s) to array taken from the below:

> So that's the same as VAR[1,0]=(...) ?  It doesn't really "look" very
>   much like prepend to me.
>
> -- Greg Klanderman (http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00031.html)

The `${^path}(-/N)` expands the [glob qualifires](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-qualifiers_002c-globbing) `-/N` on the each `$path` elements.
(Without `^` in the [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), the last elements of array will be evaluated, so it is mandatory in this case.)

The glob qualifires `-/N` means that "symbolic links  and the files they point to"(`-`) the "directory"(`/`). And when it does not match anything do not raise errors (`N`).

In short, it would keep exsisting directories only for `$path`.